# swift support for comma operator?

Tags: swift, swift-playground

The following code seems to work just fine in swift:

```
for (var i = 0, x = 0; i < 10; i++, x++) {
    println ("i is \(i) x is \(x)");
}
```

1)  I can not find any documentation that says the comma operator is supported or not.

2)  The swift-playground sometimes crashes when modifying a for loop to include a second counter (, x = 0).

I'm I wrong to expect the above code to work, or is this just a playground issue?  Any reference to documentation on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is supported and it seems to work fine for me in a Playground in Xcode 6.1 GM 2 (6A1046a). You can find the documentation for it in the [Language Reference section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AboutTheLanguageReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH29-XID_508) of the Swift Programming Language guide.

Specifically (slightly tweaked to fit the SO answer format):

```
for-statement → for ­for-init ­; ­expression­­ ; ­expression­ ­code-block­
for-statement → for­ (­ for-init­ ; ­expression­ ; ­expression­ ­) ­code-block­

for-init → variable-declaration­ expression-list

expression → prefix-expression­ binary-expressions
expression-list → expression­ | expression­ , ­expression-list
```

Note the `,` in `expression-list`

Comment: I looked right past it.  There might be a problem with the playground editor.  If I can reproduce it, I will open a bug (radar) with Apple.  Thanks for pointing out the obvious.

Comment: @Bill It's easy to look past this stuff. I'd be curious to know if you can reproduce the issue with the Playground editor; I haven't had any issues with this particular syntax yet, but I've seen quite a lot of other bugs with the Playground.

Comment: I can reproduce it.  Paste in my code from above.  Remove all references to x.  First add back ,x=0.  Then add back ,x++.  This is all on the first line.  My version of Xcode is the same -Version 6.1 (6A1046a).

Comment: @Bill Yep, looks like the compiler crashes just after typing `x` in `x++`. Interesting... definitely radar filing time.

Comment: Opened as 18643692.  I forgot to use Safari and had to re-enter it - silly me.  Thanks for the second pair of eyes.